# Smartphone-controlled motion alarm system

Tags: home-security

I don't want to pay for a monitored alarm system.  I would just like to install some wireless motion sensors that, either directly or via a separate controller that uses the local wifi:

1. Can be armed/disarmed from a smartphone
2. Push alerts to registered smartphones when motion is detected while system is armed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not wanting to pay an ongoing monthly fee for either monitoring or cell service of alerts really limits the options here.

You can cobble together D-Link WiFi Motion Sensors (currently [DCH-S150](http://us.dlink.com/products/connected-home/wi-fi-motion-sensor/), about $40/apiece) and control them using [IFTTT.com](https://ifttt.com/dlink_motion_sensor).

[iSmartAlarm](https://www.ismartalarm.com/us/) appears to be a step up, with a wireless hub that integrates a siren and the ability to link and control many devices: extra $30 motion sensors, $25 door/window sensors, cameras, and electrical switches.

Other "self-monitored" systems are built around cameras:  E.g., [Canary](https://canary.is/) security devices are under $200 and each one includes full HD video as well as motion detection, humidity and temperature measurement, and a siren.  [Piper](https://getpiper.com/) is similar, and [Novi](http://www.novisecurity.com/) has a smoke detector built in to each ceiling-mount unit.

Answer (score 1):

Does the D-LINK DCH-S150 (http://us.dlink.com/products/connected-home/wi-fi-motion-sensor/) suits you?

It's connected to your local wifi and registered onto your D-LINK account which leads to a control from the D-LINK app on your smartphone.